# How could I Embedded Video in a UIView like Path?

Tags: ios, video, path

[image]

the picture is snapped from Path App, u can see, In the table view,there is a video clip, when I touched on the play button, the video plays without changing to full screen.

it seems the video is Embedded in the table view?

How to do this? could u give a example? thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from one of my projects, just adjust this to fit your needs:

```
    NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];

    player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 690, 370);

    // Here is where you set the control Style like fullscreen or embedded
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    //player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    //player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    //player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinished) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

    UIView *movieBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 400)];
    [movieBox setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [movieBox addSubview:player.view];
    [self.view addSubview:movieBox];
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

    player.contentURL = movieUrl; 

    [player play];
```

Comment: releasing and stuff is missing here, I leave that up to you :)

Comment: it seems works,  but the play button do not like the picture shows.

Comment: I don't know the path app, but in that case I guess it's really a web view inside the app. I only know this arrow style from videos embedded in websites.

Comment: thanks a ton.   I encountered with another problem, could u help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929107/ios-how-could-uisavevideoatpathtosavedphotosalbum-return-the-saved-video-path

Comment: hello,@ jimpic i have use this code on my button click event but it will not play video.... it will display black screen..

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated. Use AVPlayerViewController instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use `HTML5` in `UIWebView` for video playing as intial is poster image and on click video starts as per your requirement.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17922148/1106035) link to play video in webView.

Hope its helpful!

Comment: dead link, please fix or put info on here