# IOS -how could UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum return the saved video path?

Tags: iphone, ios, video

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];


    //get the videoURL 
    NSString *tempFilePath = [videoURL path];


    if ( UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath))
    {
      // Copy it to the camera roll.
      UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), tempFilePath);
    } 
}
```

I use  UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum to save video recorded. And I want to know the absolute path in the album where I saved the recorded video.

How could I get the saved Path? UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum does not return any.

and in the callback function  video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo: there is still not path info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know..  You cannot get the path for the videos saved in the Photo album.  If you want the files list to  be replayed from your app.  You can have all the videos inside your application.

Following is your sample code to put inside didFinishPickingMedia to store the videos in side documents..  So that you can keep track of it.

```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1]];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ :%@.%@", itsIncidentType, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:incidentDate], @"mp4"];
    [dateFormatter release];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder
    NSURL *videoURL = [imageInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    self.itsVideoName = fileName;
    [webData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",dataPath,fileName] atomically:TRUE];
```

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem and solved it that way.

Create category of PHAsset with two methods

`PHAsset+Picking.h`

```
#import <Photos/Photos.h>

@interface PHAsset (Picking)

+ (PHAsset *)retrievePHAssetWithLocalIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

+ (void)saveVideoFromCameraToPhotoAlbumWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
                                     completion:(void(^)(PHAsset * _Nullable asset))completion;

@end
```

`PHAsset+Picking.m`

```
@implementation PHAsset (Picking)

+ (PHAsset *)retrievePHAssetWithLocalIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    PHAsset *asset = nil;
    if (identifier) {
        PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[identifier] options:nil];
        asset = result.firstObject;
    }

    return asset;
}

+ (void)saveVideoFromCameraToPhotoAlbumWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
                                     completion:(void(^)(PHAsset * _Nullable asset))completion
{
    // get URL to file from picking media info
    NSURL *url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    __block PHAssetChangeRequest *changeRequest = nil;
    __block PHObjectPlaceholder *assetPlaceholder = nil;
    // save video file to library
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        changeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:url];
        assetPlaceholder = changeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset;
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            // get saved object as PHAsset 
            PHAsset *asset = [PHAsset retrievePHAssetWithLocalIdentifier:assetPlaceholder.localIdentifier];
            completion(asset);
        } else {
            completion(nil);
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Then use method **saveVideoFromCameraToPhotoAlbumWithInfo** inside

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
        Weakify(self);
        void (^processAsset)(PHAsset *, NSDictionary *) = ^void(PHAsset *asset, NSDictionary *mediaInfo) {
            [PHImageManager.defaultManager requestAVAssetForVideo:asset
                                                      options:nil
                                                resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset,
                                                                AVAudioMix *audioMix,
                                                                NSDictionary *assetInfo)
             {
                 Strongify(self);
                 if ([asset respondsToSelector:@selector(URL)]) {

                     // URL to video file here -->
                     NSURL *videoURL = [asset performSelector:@selector(URL)];
                     // <--

                 } else {
                     // asset hasn't property URL
                     // it is can be AVComposition (e.g. user chose slo-mo video)
                 }
             }];
        };

        if (UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera == picker.sourceType) {
            // save video from camera
            [PHAsset saveVideoFromCameraToPhotoAlbumWithInfo:info completion:^(PHAsset *asset) {
                // processing saved asset
                processAsset(asset, info);
            }];
        } else {
            // processing existing asset from library
            processAsset(info[UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset], info);
        }
    } else {
        // image processing
    }
}
```